# What is the sign convention for the primary counter balancing current of a 2-winding transformer?

Tags: transformer, secondary-winding, primary-winding

In a two winding 1-phase transformer on load,

Primary Current(I1) = No Load Current(Io) + Primary Counter Balancing Current(I2')

So, We get I1 = Io + I2'

We know I2' = K*I2, where K is the turns ratio

But some places, It's mentioned I2' = -K*I2 (Accounting to the 180 degree phase shift)

I am confused what to consider.

Answer (score 0):

> *We know I2' = K*I2, where K is the turns ratio*

No, that is incorrect.

The negative sign **must** be used if you want to be accurate because the two currents (I2' and I2) are certainly of opposite phase. If they weren't opposite in phase then, I2' **wouldn't** be a "counter-balancing current" and, the impact of this is that there would be significant flux in the core **due to load currents**.

This would lead to a massive increase in the secondary induced emf which, in turn would lead to even greater load currents and things spiral to infinity.